# When you use Android Studio are you working with MVC?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, android-studio

I know in Xcode when you write an app, you have controller, model, views.
android studio doesn't have a Controller specific. Do you think in android studio are working with MVC?

Comment: I think quite many projects done with Xcode have no views or controllers, so I think you should be more specific. Also there's always some controller behind the view in any UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No but you can build it quite easily**:

On Android, you always have these XML which represent the views (actually you can do all programatically but a better practice will invite you to use these XML because they're more flexible) and they're in the ressources. The problem comes when you do custom views because you need to put a bit of logic in that and then it is part of your java code.

Then the controller is, basically, the activity but the fragments contain also, theoretically a bit of logic so they're like hybrid between controller and view (I, personally, consider them as controller but my pair developer as a view). 
Then the models are very easy to separate... At the end you can get something like this: (but I do not if you would call it MVC)

```
-java
 |_model
    |_user.java
 |_view
    |_customView.java (extends View for example)
 |_controller
    |_MainActivity.java
    |_fragment_contained_in_main_activity_inflating_Custom_View.java
-res
 |_layout
    |_customView_layout.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Android the activity or fragment is the "controller". You write the controlling code in java and the views in XML. You can make model classes as .java files and when populating data from a server wrap those model classes in an Array or List to be used and placed onto your view via the activity code.